# How to add datestamp to a executable configuration file variable

Tags: app-config, configuration-files

I have a batch file process that runs and creates a file. When it was originally written it had a static folder path to create a file. I have modified the script to set a datestamp variable that creates a folder with the datestamp as the name of the folder then places the file inside of that folder.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value')
do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%"
set "dirOutput=C:\Temp\Output\%datestamp%"
mkdir %dirOuput%
```

There is another process that runs an executable that has a configuration file that has the original hard coded folder path in it.

```
<appsetings>

<add key="Target" value="C:\Temp\Output"/>

</appsettings>
```

Is there a way that I can modify the configuration file for the executable to match the folder path with the datestamp variable that I created in the batch file?

ie.

```
<appsetings>

<add key="Target" value="C:\Temp\Output\(Current date)"/>

</appsettings>
```